# send hex string to serial through javascript

Tags: javascript, serial-port, hex

I'm trying to send a hex string to a serial port using Web Serial Api and javascript.

```
function ascii_to_hexa(str) {
    var arr1 = [];
    for (var n = 0, l = str.length; n < l; n++) {
        var hex = Number(str.charCodeAt(n)).toString(16);
        arr1.push("\\x" + hex);
    }
    return arr1.join("");
}

    
       for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(master_array)) {       
                converted_hex += ascii_to_hexa(value) + "\\x0d";
        }

        compose_hex_command_with_extra_data = "\\x01\\x44\\x52\\x54\\x02" + converted_hex + "\\x04";
        console.log(compose_hex_command_with_extra_data );

        serialDevices[1].write(compose_hex_command_with_extra_data );
```

Each separate command needs to have a carriage return after it. This is why i'm adding a "x0d" after each iteration of the `ascii_to_hexa` function. When I console log the read out, it's correct. Here is an example of `compose_hex_command_with_extra_data` as printed to the console:

```
\x01\x44\x52\x54\x02\x52\x53\x2b\x30\x32\x2e\x30\x30\x0d\x52\x43\x2d\x30\x2e\x35\x30\x0d\x52\x41\x30\x34\x35\x0d\x2b\x30\x2e\x37\x35\x0d\x2b\x31\x2e\x30\x30\x0d\x2d\x31\x2e\x30\x30\x0d\x30\x32\x31\x0d\x2b\x30\x2e\x37\x35\x0d\x04
```

Now, this does not work within the loaded script on the page where it says `serialDevices[1].write(compose_hex_command_with_extra_data );`
but if I copy this exact command and copy the string of hex output from the console so that the console says:

```
serialDevices[1].write('\x01\x44\x52\x54\x02\x52\x53\x2b\x30\x32\x2e\x30\x30\x0d\x52\x43\x2d\x30\x2e\x35\x30\x0d\x52\x41\x30\x34\x35\x0d\x2b\x30\x2e\x37\x35\x0d\x2b\x31\x2e\x30\x30\x0d\x2d\x31\x2e\x30\x30\x0d\x30\x32\x31\x0d\x2b\x30\x2e\x37\x35\x0d\x04');
```

it works! So how can I reconcile this? To my eye, I'm sending the correct string to the "serial write" command but the serial machine is not responding unless I explicitly spell it out and don't send it as a variable value.

Answer (score 0):

The answer came in the form of `decodeURIComponent()`. Simply replace the "\\x" instances with a "%" and wrap the composed hex string in the decodeURIComponent function and it works!

```
function ascii_to_hexa(str) {
    var arr1 = [];
    for (var n = 0, l = str.length; n < l; n++) {
        var hex = Number(str.charCodeAt(n)).toString(16);
        arr1.push("%" + hex);
    }
    return arr1.join("");
}

    
       for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(master_array)) {       
                converted_hex += ascii_to_hexa(value) + "%0d";
        }

        compose_hex_command_with_extra_data = "%01%44%52%54%02" + converted_hex + "%04";
       

        serialDevices[1].write(decodeURIComponent(compose_hex_command_with_extra_data ));
```